# visual studio app settings USAGE

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I am not sure how to use Application Setting with custom user types.

For example, in a time tracking system, I would like to have an application setting (with application scope) that says how many hours a day an employee must account for. There is a custom user type, TimeQuantity, with some factory methods and a constructor with a signature of TimeQuantity(double, TimeSliceUnit), where the unit is just an enum.

I can get the settings designer to recognize the TimeQuantity type, but am at a loss as how to provide the setting value (8d hours, here).

Must I create some sort of settings provider? Build the object outside of the designer? Roll my own settings infrastructure?

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  It is right at the top of the dialog.  Make sure the class is public.

Comment: The class of interest is both public & serializable. The browse for type dialog does not include the project (ie, MyProject.Domain) in it's list of offerings, so I cannot select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was just battling the same issue. As far as I can tell, visual studio doesn't allow you to browse to a type in your current project; you can only browse to types in a referenced assembly. However, you can type the fully qualified name of the type you want to use in the settings 'Select a Type' dialog box like shown below. Note that this won't work until your project has been built with the type you want to reference already included. (Same is true with referenced assemblies.) Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I found this out (eventually!) & forgot I had left this question open. Cheers

Comment: As an aside, it would be nice if the dialog had some helpful clue (ie, "Select a Type or add the 'Selected Type' below") to make it more intuitive for the first time user.